# Use Haversine package to compare all distances possibilities of a csv list of longitude and latitude

Tags: python, python-3.x, distance, haversine

I have a list of lon and lat as csv file and i want to calculate the all distances, the file have arguments like this `(-18.4392969, -40.2688762)
(-8.3905896, -37.4957717)
(-19.952862, -33.173232)`

edit: i want to make a code that give me something like this: distance between point A to B and C
and B to A and C, C to A and B, and save it to a list distances.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include code that attempts a solution. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a python function to compute the great-circle distance between two locations on Earth given their (latitude, longitude) tuples:

```
import math

def distance(p1, p2):
    R = 6371 # mean radius of Earth in km

    cphi_1 = math.cos(math.radians(p1[0]))
    cphi_2 = math.cos(math.radians(p2[0]))

    d_phi = math.radians(p2[0] - p1[0])
    d_lam = math.radians(p2[1] - p1[1])

    a =  math.sin(d_phi / 2) ** 2
    a += math.sin(d_lam / 2) ** 2 * cphi_1 * cphi_2
    return 2 * R * math.atan2(abs(a) ** 0.5, abs(1 - a) ** 0.5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(distance((40.2342, -17.9834), (13.3298, -53.1698)))
```

I tested it against [this online calculator](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), however your may wish to do your own testing before using the code above in your own code.

**EDIT** to compute all unique pair-wise distances without duplicates, use something like

```
from itertools import combinations
distances = list(map(distance, *zip(*combinations(lat_lon_list, 2))))
```

Comment: actually i could calculate this using haversine package, but i want to make a code that give me something like this: distance between point A to B and C,,,
   and B to A and C,,,    C to A and B, and save it to a list distances.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. I thought you were looking for a haversine package to compute the distance for you.

Comment: @FoE updated my answer to include code for all pair-wise combinations